# Assembly 8086 - xor operations

Tags: assembly, x86

I just wonder what is the meaning of this code:

```
XOR EAX,EBX 
XOR EBX,EAX
XOR EAX,EBX
```

Comment: EAX and EBX are registers.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Purpose  XOR is stands for "exclusive or" and is a bitwise operation.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR

Comment: There is an `XCHG` instruction, that does exactly the same.

Comment: @ruslik: And I believe XCHG has the advantage of being fully atomic, not that I think that'll be an issue here, right?

Comment: Also, on registers, XCHG could theoretically be optimized away by the register rename engine (I don't know if the current generation of x86 bothers to do this - it does do it for reg-reg MOV) whereas that sequence of XORs has to go through the ALU and has to be executed in order.

Comment: @Kim Sun-wu: atomicity is not a problem here, because the memory is not involved. I can think of two reasons: 1) `xor` version is mapped directly to C operation, and 2) `xor` could be even faster than `xchg` on new processors.

Comment: @ruslik: even without memory, there could be an interrupt between any of the instructions that might change EBX or EAX.

Comment: @Nathan Fellman: Interrupt routines are not allowed to change registers. Also, atomicity usually reffers to the values in memory, not in register. It would be werd for another thread to expect that it will find a certain variable in a certain register.

Comment: @ruslik: are not allowed to change registers *by whom*?  Hardware certainly does not limit you.

Comment: @Nathan Fellman: by definition. A hardware interrupt (it's the only one that could interrupt this sequence) is expected to preserve the registers. Without this assumption it's just impossible to write a program.

Comment: @ruslik: I understand. I'm looking at it from the point of view of one who does hardware verification, which is about what is *possible*, whereas you're looking at it from the point of view of software conventions, which are about what is *allowed*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's [xor swapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).

Doing it on registers does not suffer the usual ugly failure case.

Comment: In other words, it swaps the contents of eax and ebx.